# Problem: When a method is called, the method of the parent is called, not the inheritor C#

Tags: c#, oop

Help me please, I have Entity class in which the collider function.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Player player = new Player();
        Enemy enemy = new Enemy();
        
        enemy.Collide(enemy, player);
    }
}
public abstract class Entity
{
    public virtual void Visit(Enemy enemy) { }
    public virtual void Visit(Player enemy) { }
    public virtual void Visit(Entity enemy) { }
    
    public virtual void Collide(Entity ent1, Entity ent2)
    {
        ent2.Visit(ent1);
    }
}
public class Enemy : Entity
{
    public override void Visit(Enemy enemy) { }
    public override void Visit(Player enemy) { }
}
public class Player : Entity
{
    public override void Visit(Enemy enemy) { }
    public override void Visit(Player enemy) { }
}
```

For example, I have 2 entities Player: Entity and Enemy: Entity;

When calling the Visit method in Collide method, where ent1 is Player and ent2 is Enemy, the method of the child class Enemy :: Visit (Player player) must be called, but the Entity :: Visit (Entity entity) method is called.

At the same time, when outputting ent1.GetType () it writes that it is Player, and ent2.GetType () is Enemy. Why does the compiler do this and how to fix it?

If I manually cast ent1 in Player, then everything works, but I need versatility, since there are more objects in my game.

Comment: Why is this tagged C++ *and* C#? It sems to be C#. Please post a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Assume I'm the Collide function, I got an Entity object, how should I know it's a Player or an Enemy? Wait, there is a `Visit(Entity entity)` right? that's it, I'll call this.

That's what happens when the compiler builds your game.

You may rewrite the `Visit(Entity entity)` in `Entity`, check the actual data type of your object, call the right one, then you just implement what you really care, just like what you did in `Enemy`.

Or (I think it's better to) delete other functions but `Visit(Entity entity)`, check the type in your `Enemy` override, then do what you want.

Comment: Hi, I understand that in Visit (Entity entity) you can make a handler (for example a switch) and cast to the desired type, then call the desired Visit, but the problem is that I use the Visitor pattern and in Visit (Entity entity) I will have to endlessly add new objects games, it seems to me it's not right.

Comment: You missed the visitor part of the visitor pattern. The aim of the visitor pattern is to separate the behavior from the data, so it creates a "visitor" to define how the data is read and how to manipulate it. So you need a visitor -- maybe called `EntitiyVisitor` -- to contain the methods in your `Entity` and do the job. You can google the pattern and read the example.

Sorry for the late reply.